# Can we create route by artisan command in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Can we create a route by running an artisan command in Laravel? If yes what is the command for it. I m a beginner please help.

Comment: why would you wanna do such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to

just open the routes file

```
routes/web.php
```

and add your route like that

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
  return 'Hello World';
});
```

check the docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no generic generator command for generating route definitions and appending them to route files.